# Need to optimize a simple loop over 200,000 records

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, abap

I am wondering if anyone can optimize following code:

```
LOOP AT dispinstock.
  SELECT matnr SUM( gesme ) SUM( verme ) SUM( einme ) SUM( ausme )
         INTO (dispinstock-matnr, dispinstock-gesme,
               dispinstock-verme, dispinstock-einme, dispinstock-ausme)
         FROM lqua
         WHERE matnr = dispinstock-matnr
         AND lgnum = 'xxxxx'
         AND ( lgtyp IN zsd_t301_n
          OR ( lgtyp >= '900' AND lgtyp <= '903' ) )
          GROUP BY matnr.
    MODIFY dispinstock.
  ENDSELECT.
ENDLOOP.
```

dispinstock 170.000 records,

LQUA 210.000 records (will be larger > 1.500.000 records soon)

This loop take more than 3 minutes.
Would it be better to use hashed table instead?
Any help or idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the select out of the loop - pull all the data you need from lqua into a separate internal table in a single select statement.  Then do a read on the second table inside the loop.  Use a hash/sorted table or use a binary search.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, will try that. Wasn't sure if it helps if I take the select out of the loop.

Comment: In my experience, it definitely does.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to a system at the  moment or I'd post a code sample for you.

Comment: +1 - er, +170.000. The code above throws 170.000 select statements at the database, all containing ORed conditions, therefore bypassing the buffers and eliminating most of the index optimizations. You're lucky your DB hasn't responred with something unfriendly so far...

Answer (score 4):

You should also think about using a field symbol rather than using the modify.

```
field-symbols: <dispinstock> like line of dispinstock.
loop at dispinstock assigning <dispinstock>.
  " some work
  <dispinstock>-gesme = new value..
  "...
 endloop
```

This way you reduce the number of times you read the dispinstock table and change the value directly.

Comment: I realized this a couple hours after I posted - meant to include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I´m sure that your internal table dispinstock does not contain 170.000 distinct materials! 
So I suggest to build a table of distinct MATNRs and start the select with a FOR ALL ENTRIES IN ...

...
AND ( lgtyp IN zsd_t301_n          OR ( lgtyp >= '900' AND lgtyp <= '903' ) )

Insert one row into your range object zsd_t301_n and delete the OR statement

Sign OPTION LOW HIGH

I    BT     900 903

Answer (score 0):

If the line that says "MODIFY dispinstock" means "update a row in the dispinstock table with the values that were just acquired from the SELECT", then you could probably replace the LOOP and the SELECT with a single MERGE statement.

Something like

```
MERGE INTO dispinstock
USING (  SELECT matnr, SUM( gesme ) gesme,  SUM( verme ) verme, SUM( einme ) einme,  SUM( ausme ) ausme
         FROM lqua
         WHERE lgnum = 'xxxxx'
         AND ( lgtyp IN zsd_t301_n
          OR ( lgtyp >= '900' AND lgtyp <= '903' ) )
          GROUP BY matnr
      ) lqua
ON lqua.matnr = dispinstock.matnr
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  gesme = l.gesme, verme = l.verme, einme = l.einme, ausme = l.ausme
```